# Wordpress Multisite “Error establishing a database connection” issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I studied lots of questions on Stackoverflow **[Such as This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724781/wordpress-multisite-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-localhost)**, and on net , but none solved my issue.

I have multisite working on domain X working well. Now I moved it to my server with all DB URL Replace. Also I changed `wp-config` and `htaccess` accordingly.

The issue is when I set `define('MULTISITE', false);` is `false` then only base site runs and for other subsites it gives `404` error.

But I have multisite , I just moved to my instance and must have `MULTISITE` as `true` for multisite to work.

Now when i set it as true , I get

> Error establishing a database connection

error. I don't know what is actually going on . I debugged but could not get it solved.

My config code for multisite

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
//define('RELOCATE',true);


define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
$base = '/';
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/smart_facility_linux/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

//My Htaccess ( it does not have any issue)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /smart_facility_linux/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^privacy-statement.html /privacy-statement [L]
```

Comment: please add the complete error information...

Comment: It just gives **get Error establishing a database connection** check in bold in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it & it worked  **:)**

In `wp_blogs` table ,

**Old structure** was

```
Domain : localhost/smart_facility_linux
Path : /
```

But i changed it to to make it work as follows:

**For root site:**

```
Domain : localhost
Path : /smart_facility_linux/
```

**For sub site 1 (any subsite under main site ,I just gave example) :**

```
Domain : localhost
Path : /smart_facility_linux/subsite1/
```