# Why is a redirect occurring when multisite is true?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site hosted externally.  My PC recently had to be rebuilt and I am trying to setup the site on my development PC.  So far I have:

1. Installed Xampp
2. Exported the database using PHPMyAdmin from my hosting company and imported it using PHPMyAdmin on my development PC.
3. Downloaded the .php files using Filezilla to: htdocs\mysite.
4. Create a default wordpress app on my PC and copy the wp_config.php to: htdocs\mysite (replacing the existing wp_config.php).
5. In htdocs\mysite\wp_config.php: change: `define( 'DB_NAME', 'defaultsite' );` to: `define( 'DB_NAME', 'mysite' );`  mysite was the site downloaded.

The first issue I had was that when I navigated to: http://localhost/mysite; I was redirected to: [www.mysite.co.uk](http://www.mysite.co.uk).  I then came across this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/my-wordpress-site-gets-redirected-automatically-to-the-old-site-any-known-soluti

Adding the following to wp_config.php resolved the issue:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/mysite');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/mysite');
```

I can now access the admin dashboard and all the webpages.  The problem I have now is that the site at the hosting company is a multisite.  I have tried adding: `define( 'MULTISITE', true );`to wp_config.php, however I am now redirected to: [www.mysite.co.uk](http://www.mysite.co.uk) again.  I did some further research and tried executing this SQL statement:

```
update wp_options set option_value='http://localhost/mysite' where option_name='siteurl' or option_name='home'
```

It made no difference.  Why is a redirect occurring when multisite is true?

**Update**

Following on from CBroes' comment I have tried this as well:

```
update wp_site set domain ='localhost\mysite'
update wp_sitemeta set meta_value='http://localhost/mysite' where meta_key='siteurl'
```

Now if I add: `define( 'MULTISITE', true );` to my wp_config.php I see this error: `localhost redirected you too many times.`  If I remove that line from wp_config.php, then the primary site and primary admin work as expected, however the multi site does not.

**Update 2**

I have run the following SQL statement (as stated in Sabin Chirilas answer here: [Wordpress Multisite "Error establishing a database connection" in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724781/wordpress-multisite-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-localhost)):

```
update `wp_blogs` set domain='localhost.blog'
```

Comment: Try checking the `site` and `sitemeta` tables, there might be entries containing the wrong domain as well.

Comment: @CBroe, could you have a look at the update to my question?

Comment: Why are you creating your own wp-config now, instead of using the one that was already on the server, and modify only the database credentials in there? Also, a multi-site setup requires a different .htaccess than a single-site WP. Did you use the version from the server for that, or are you creating your own/using the default one?

Comment: @CBroe, no reason other than the all of the site (except the multisite) works with a fresh wp_config.php.  I have not made any changes to the .htaccess.  What should the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE be? I have put the site here: localhost/mysite.  I have tried: localhost and I get the redirect too many times error.  I have also tired: localhost and then I just see an error: Error establishing a database connection.

Comment: _“What should the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE be? I have put the site here: localhost/mysite.”_ - then you will also have to tell wordpress that you want it to run in a sub-directory (assuming that was not the case in the live version already.) I would really recommend against setting up local development enviroments in a different way, than the live version - you are just asking for trouble by doing that. If the live version did not run in a sub-directory as well - then set up a proper virtual host first of all, plus a custom local host name, and then use that to access the project.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess you mean something like this: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/

Comment: @CBroe, managed to get it working.  The only problem now is that when I log out of the admin dashboard; it redirects to: http://wp-login.php/?loggedout=true (which doesn't exist); instead of: http://localhost.blog/wp-login.php/?loggedout=true (which does exist).  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You might have to include the `/wp/` path in your siteurl.

Comment: Thanks.  Were would I put that: PATH_CURRENT_SITE?

Comment: No, `siteurl` …

Comment: Just in the wp_config or in the database as well?